# How to make the income distribution of a country follows the 80:20 rule?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, machine-learning, data-analysis

**My main question:**

Let's imagine a country with a population of $n$ people. Each person has a certain amount of income in a certain year. When we calculate the income distribution of this country, we found that 80% of the total income in this country is only contributed by 1% of the population. If we assume that the government has the ability to **add**, but not **deduct** any person's income, how much is the **minimum** amount of incentive for each person that the government has to offer? Also, assume that $n$ doesn't change for the whole year

When we add each person's current income with each person's incentive, these two rules must be fulfilled at the end of the year:

1. 20% of the population contributes 80% of the total income
2. The government must achieve the total income target

**I will try to formulate this problem mathematically:**

Let $x$ be a vector of income for each person in the country
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
... \\ 
x_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and $X$ be a vector of $x$ that is sorted in descending order. So i guess, 
 $X = P \cdot x$ 
where $P$ is an $nxn$ permutation matrix (?)

The total income in that country is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$$

(And at the end of the year, the result of this sum above must achieve a certain level of total income)

And there's $X^c$ , which is a vector of cumulative income, whereby
$$
X^c_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{n-i+1}
$$
And lastly we have $I$, a vector of income contribution percentage for the top $i$ highest earning person. The vector is defined as:
$$
I = X^c \cdot \frac{100}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}
$$
So basically, $I_i$% of the total income in this country is contributed by $100(\frac{i}{n})$% of the population.

How do i come up with a vector $v$ (minimum incentive), so that when i add $X$ and $v$:

1. 80% of the total new income (after incentive) must be contributed by 20% of the population
   $$
   0.8\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} + v_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{j} (X_{i} + v_{i})
   $$
   , where
   $$
   0.2 \le \frac{j}{n} \le 1
   $$
2. The country must achieve its yearly total income target $T$
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i} + v_{i})=T$$

Context: I'm a data scientist and I think this problem can be effectively solved using computer (like linear programming or machine learning?). I want to know what method should i use, but before that, I also want to know the mathematical thinking behind it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want 80% of new income to be owned by at least 20% of population ($j \geq 0.2 \cdot n)$, or exactly 20% ($j = 0.2 \cdot n$)?

Comment: Hi @mihaild, more than 20% is good. However, i want to find the **minimum** incentive so that we can reach 20% first.

Comment: Shouldn't your definition of $X_i^c$ be something like $\sum_{j=i}^n X_{n-j+1}$ or something similar?